# Zooming a tmux pane to *half* screen?

Tags: tmux

I know how to zoom a pane to the full screen: prefix + z.

Is it possible to zoom a pane to *half* screen, or zoom two panes, each occupying a half screen?

**Why though?** Because I have two screens, on the left of which I write code, when I zoom a pane to the full screen, the code is pushed all the way to the left side of the left screen, which causes a lot of inconvenience.

Comment: Nested `tmux`, but this will cause its own inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something working with layouts. When you do `tmux list-windows` you will get a line of output that includes a complicated string giving the current pane layout, eg

```
... [layout f6f5,80x23,0,0[80x6,0,0,0,80x16,0,7,1]] ...
```

You cannot change this string as the first number (f6f5 here) is a checksum. 
You need to remove the initial `[layout` and final `]`, and save this string.
If you now manually manipulate the panes to the new configuration you want and save the new layout string, you can switch between the two layouts eg with

```
tmux select-layout 'f6f5,80x23,0,0[80x6,0,0,0,80x16,0,7,1]'
```